# Google's API Node JS Client - How To Get Authenticated User's Contacts from Contacts API?

Tags: node.js, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I've successfully authenticated user accounts w/ Google's Node.js Client, but I can't figure out how to fetch a User's Contacts?

The Contacts API is not listed in [Google's APIs Explorer.](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/)

So, there is no simple syntax to get Contacts.

How can I get these?

Comment: found any solutions yet? i am having the same problem

Comment: I am getting them currently by using Google's Node.js Client for authentication and then I use the token I received with a modified variation of this fork of 'Google-Contacts' which uses oauth2 authentication.